# Eclipse ADT から Android Studio に移行する際の注意点

Tags: android-studio, eclipse

Eclipse [ADT](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) with Android SDK で開発していたアプリの開発環境を Android Studio に移行する際に、よくおかす間違いや誤解、注意すべきポイントなどありましたら教えてください。

Comment: 質問が曖昧なので答えにくいです。移行作業でのことを知りたいのか、ツールの違いを知りたいのかはっきりしません。

Comment: すいません、どちらかと言うと移行作業です。質問内容を編集しました。

Comment: eclipseのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この回答では、プロジェクト構成を変更する前提とさせていただきます。

## プロジェクト構成が異なる

ビルドシステムが根本的に変更となります。そのため、時間がかかると思ってください。
しかし、その時間を相殺できるほど便利になります。

### ディレクトリ構成を真似る

ほかの方の説明にあるように現在のディレクトリ構成でビルドすることは可能です。
Android Studioで新規プロジェクトを作成し、そのディレクトリ構成を真似たり、設定を反映したりすることをお勧めいたします。

### ソース管理を伴う場合

ソースコードの管理をされている場合は、ファイルの再配置が発生します。
そのため、リリース等のタイミングを考慮したうえで作業を行うのとあわせて、履歴が途切れないように注意してください。
また、ビルドシステムが異なることから、.gitignore等の無視リストをメンテナンスすべきです。
Android studioはSCM(git等)に対応しているので、移行ついでに名前の変更等も簡単にできます。

- 主要なフォルダ構成について

  - Project/src → Project/src/main/java
  - Project/res → Project/src/main/res
  - ProjectTest/src → Project/src/androidTest/src/main/java
- レイアウト(XMLのxmlns記載)について

  - http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.project.package → http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto

上記以外の主要な変更については以下のとおり。移行当時の[コミット](https://github.com/indication/OpenRedmine/commit/27a09046c633f3fe148fa87af9584486a14be8b8?diff=unified)から抜粋。

```
変更: .gitignore
追加: .idea/.name
追加: .idea/compiler.xml
追加: .idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
追加: .idea/encodings.xml
追加: .idea/gradle.xml
追加: .idea/misc.xml
追加: .idea/modules.xml
追加: .idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
追加: .idea/vcs.xml
削除: SampleProject/.checkstyle
削除: SampleProject/.classpath
追加: SampleProject/.gitignore (上位の.gitignore で記述すれば不要かも)
削除: SampleProject/.project
削除: SampleProject/.settings/
追加: SampleProject/SampleProject.iml
追加: SampleProject/build.gradle
削除: SampleProject/libs/android-support-v4.jar
削除: SampleProject/pom.xml (marvenへのリリースは行わないため)
変更: SampleProject/proguard-project.txt
削除: SampleProject/project.properties
名前変更: SampleProject/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml （SampleProject/AndroidManifest.xml から）
追加: SampleProjectProject.iml
追加: build.gradle
追加: gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
追加: gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
追加: gradlew
追加: gradlew.bat
追加: settings.gradle
```

### ビルドやデバッグ

ADTと似たようなアイコンがあるので、開発・テストは直感的にわかるかと存じます。
しかし、リリースビルドの場合は、いくつかの設定を行う必要があります。
メニューのBuild→Generate Signed APKでリリース版のAPKを出力することができます。
しかし、毎回設定するのは厳しいので、build.gradleに記述し、
左下の□→Gradle→assembleRelease という手順を使えるように設定することをお勧めします。

なお、ビルドログについては、左下の□→GradleConsole で確認できます。

### 証明書

ご存知だとは思いますが、デバッグ用証明書やリリース用の証明書は引き継がれません。
実機でデバッグモードで実行する場合は再インストールになる可能性があります。

### そのほか

Android Studioは(ヘルプ等も含めて)基本的に英語です。しかし、安心してください、日本での利用者は多いため、情報は充実している認識です。
バージョンアップも頻繁にあり、最近では減りましたが、バージョンアップにより設定が変わることがあります。チームで使用する場合は全員と同期を取らないといけないケースがあります。

Answer (score 2):

### 説明

念のため、ゼロから説明させてもらいます。以前のEclipse ADTはAndroidアプリを開発するためのEclipseプラグインでしたが、現在Android StudioというのがIntelliJ IDEAをベースとしたAndroid向きのオフィシャル開発環境になっています。移行することがおすすめです。

プロジェクトを移行する際はAndroid Studioでインポートすることができます。

Welcomeスクリーンから：

1.「Import Non-Android Studio Project」をクリック。

2. Eclipseからエクスポートしたプロジェクトを見つけて開き、build.gradleファイルを選択し、OKをクリック。
3. 次のダイアログで「Use gradle wrapper」というところを選択しOKをクリック。(Gradleホームを指定する必要はありません。)

すると、Android Studioではプロジェクト構成等が自動的にアップデートされて、新しいGradle buildファイルが作成されます。

### 他

- [IntelliJ IDEAへ移行際FAQ](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/FAQ+on+Migrating+to+IntelliJ+IDEA)をご参考ください。
- [公式ソース](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)(英語)

  ---

Comment: 一部日本語の修正を実施しました。

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと思いつくとこだと、AndroidManifest.xmlに記述していた一部の項目が、build.gradleに記述するようになったとこでしょうか。。。？